# Nuxt 3 scroll to top on route change does not work

Tags: vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js, vertical-scrolling, nuxt3

In my Nuxt 3 app I've used the code below to scroll up on route changes.
This has worked flawless since the RC phase up to version 3.5.2.

This approach is described in the [Vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/RouterOptions.html#Properties-scrollBehavior) and also referenced by the [Nuxt 3 docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/component-options#scrolltotop).

I now upgraded to Nuxt 3.6.5 and my approach does not work anymore. Sometimes the pages are not scrolled up on route changes. The behavior is kinda random, sometimes it works - sometimes it doesn't.

This is the code I've been using so far.

`app/router.options.ts`:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig>{
  scrollBehavior(_to, _from, savedPosition) {
    if (_from.name === _to.name) return

    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    }

    return { top: 0 }
  },
}
```

How can I fix this? What other approaches can I follow to make this work again?